# Send checkbox value to MySQL database without using $_POST or $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to send my checkboxes values to database without using `$_POST` and  `$_GET`.

I have three checkboxes:

```
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="gestao" name = "gestao" value = "gestao">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Gestão</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="risco" name = "risco" value = "risco">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Risco</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="TOC" name = "TOC" value = "toc">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">TOC</label>
              </div>
```

When I click them, i want to send value to mySQL database, and then retrieve it(So the checkbox remains pressed). I've already done it with a $_POST method, but i want the user just to press the checkbox and then INSERT it into the table.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're looking for [ajax](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax&rlz=1C1GIGM_enUS802US802&oq=ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i65l3.432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  which will send the request to a backend server to be processed without reloading the page. There are many libraries you could use to send an ajax request so I wont recommend one here but that's likely what you're after

Comment: If we want to get picky even AJAX uses the post or get methods.

Comment: But i'll have to have a button anyway, don't I?

Comment: Not necessarily no. You can (for example) detect when the checkbox value is changed, and trigger the AJAX request from that event instead. P.S. (using AJAX still would require the use of either $_POST or $_GET on the server side - it's still a HTTP request, which is the only way you can talk to the  server and database from a browser. I think what you probably really meant was "without refreshing the whole page"?)

Comment: Basically, you need to learn how to use AJAX in JavaScript. Look for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for ajax that sends a request to the backend server without reloading the page.

```
$(document).on('click', '#gestao, #risco, #TOC', function(){
    var gestao = $('#gestao').is(':checked') ? $('#gestao').val() : false;
    var risco= $('#risco').is(':checked') ? $('#risco').val() : false;
    var TOC= $('#TOC').is(':checked') ? $('#TOC').val() : false;

    $.post(URL, {
        gestao : gestao,
        risco  : risco,
        TOC    : TOC
    }, function(response){ 
       //Response from backend server
    })
});
```

For more reference, Check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post